# Store a file metadata in an extra file

Tags: c++, python, linux, serialization, computer-vision

I have a bunch of image files (mostly .jpg). I would like to store metadata about these files (e.g. dominant color, color distribution, maximum gradient flow field, interest points, ...). These data fields are not fixed and are not available in all images.

Right now I am storing the metadata for each file as a separate file with the same name but a different extension. The format is just text:

```
metadataFieldName1 metadataFieldValue1
metadataFieldName2 metadataFieldValue2
```

This gets me wondering, is there a better/easier way to store these metadata? I thought of ProtocolBuffer since I need to be able to read and write these information in both C++ and Python. But, how do I support the case where some metadata are not available?

Comment: Have you looked into the boost serialization infrastructure? It plays well with python I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought long on this matter and went with ProtocolBuffer to store metadata for my images. For each image e.g. Image00012.jpg, I store the metadata in Image00012.jpg.pbmd. Once I have my .proto file setup, the Python class and C++ class got auto-generated. It works very well and require me to spend little time on parsing (clearly better than writing custom reader for YAML files).

RestRisiko brings up a good point about how I should handle metadata not available. The good thing about ProtocolBuffer is it supports optional/required fields. This solves my problem on this front.

The reason I think XML and INI are not good for this purpose is because many of my metadata are complex (color distribution, ...) and require a bit of storage customization. ProtocolBuffer allows me to nest proto declaration. Plus, the size of the metadata file and the parsing speed is clearly superior to my hand-roll XML reading/writing.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you store such metadata within the image files themselves.

Most image formats support storing metadata. I think that .jpeg support it through [Exif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format).

If you're on Windows you can use the WIC to store and retrieve metadata in a [unified manner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapmetadata.setquery.aspx).

Comment: I have considered EXIF but many of my images are not in jpg format. Also I am not on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Why protocol buffers and not XML or INI files or whatever text-ish format? Just choose some format...

And what do you mean with "metadata not available"? It is up to your application to respond to such error situations...what has this to do with the format of the storage?

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://www.yaml.org. YAML is less verbose than XML and more human friendly to read.

There are YAML libraries for both C++, Python and many other languages.

Example:

```
import yaml

data = { "field1" : "value1",
         "field2" : "value2" }

serializedData = yaml.dump(data, default_flow_style=False)

open("datafile", "w").write(serializedData)
```

Comment: YAML is nice but last time I check it involves quite a bit of coding. Do you have a YAML library recommendation?

Comment: PyYAML for Python. See my added code example to the edited answer, it requires very few lines of code.

Comment: For dumping yes, but for reading that back into a C++ vector of struct is not simple.